# Can Deterministic Context free Grammars be ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I know that DCFL are unambiguous languages and DCFL languages have one-to-one correspondence with LR grammars.

But I wanted to know if there can be an instance that deterministic context free grammar is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no deterministic context-free grammar that is ambiguous since any deterministic context free grammar (DCFG) must be unambiguous.

Here is definition 2.47 of the book *introduction to the theory of computation*, third edition, by Michael Sipser.

> A deterministic context-free grammar is a context-free grammar such that every valid string has a forced handle.

Furthermore, here is definition 2.62.

> An LR($k$) grammar is a context-free grammar such that the handle of every valid string is forced by lookahead $k$.

A DCFG is the same as an LR(0) grammar. All LR($k$) grammars are unambiguous, by definition.

Comment: Ohhh. that's the reason why.Thank you also for mentioning good reference.
I am also weak at decidability problems.Can you suggest a resource for practice?

Answer (score -1):

I was also struggling with this problem. I think I might have found an ambiguous DCFG G = ({S,T,A},{a,u,v},R,S), where R is defined as

S -> ATa | aTa

T -> uv

A -> a

G is ambiguous because there are two different leftmost derivations for string auva.

S => ATa => aTa => auva

S => aTa => auva

However, G is also a DCFG because there is only one leftmost reduction

auva >-> Auva >-> ATa >-> S

which means that there are a total of three valid strings: auva, Auva, ATa. And we can show that each of them has a forced handle by enumerating all possibilities.

Comment: This is a left-most reduction, because there is no non-terminal to the left of the reduced non-terminal: $auva \rightarrowtail aTa \rightarrowtail S$. It corresponds to your second rightmost derivation. So $A\to a$ is not a forced handle; $T\to uv$ is also possible. An ambiguous grammar cannot be deterministic; intuitively, the ambiguity means that there are at least two possible choices and at some point the parser must encounter one of them. See Sipser for a more formal proof.

Comment: I'm not sure if my understanding of leftmost reduction is correct. On page 136, Sipser wrote: in a leftmost reduction, each reducing string is reduced only after all other reducing strings that lie entirely to its left. So I guess auva >-> aTa is not a valid leftmost reduction step because a lies entirely to the left of uv?

Comment: A ***reducing string*** is a string which is replaced in some ***reduce step***. (p. 135). It is not a string which just happens to appear on the right-hand side of a production. Of course, it does have to appear on the right-hand side of a production, but that's not sufficient to make it a reducing string. To be a reducing string it must actually be reduced in some step in the reduction. So $a$ is not a reducing string in $auva \rightarrowtail aTa \rightarrowtail S$, and $auva \rightarrowtail aTa$ is most certainly a leftmost reduction step.

Comment: I think I might have understood why I was wrong. When we want to tell if a reduction is a leftmost reduction, we can't use a stepwise definition like that in leftmost derivation (i.e., every step unfolds the leftmost non-terminal in the previous step). Instead, we should examine the whole reduction and check if after one reduction step (say the resulting non-terminal is X), any string lies entirely on the left of X is reduced in some later step. Am I correct?

Comment: There is a stepwise constraint: the end of each reduce step is no earlier than the symbol inserted by the previous reduce step. That's proven in Sipser, too, iirc.

Comment: I think I understand it now. I'll check the book for the proof. Thank you so much for your clarification.